# Python regex partial extract

Tags: python, regex, extract, partial

I want to find all data enclosed in `[[  ]]` these brackets.

> [[aaaaa]] -> aaaaa

My python code (using re library) was

```
la = re.findall(r'\[\[(.*?)\]\]', fa.read())
```

What if I want to extract only 'a' from `[[a|b]]`

Any concise regular expression for this task? ( extract data before `|` )

Or should I use additional if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
r'\[\[([^\]|]*)(?=.*\]\])'
```

`([^\]|]*)` will match until a `|` or `]` is found. And `(?=.*\]\])` is a lookahead to ensure that `]]` is matched on RHS of match.

**Testing:**

```
>>> re.search( r'\[\[([^\]|]*)(?=.*\]\])', '[[aaa|bbb]]' ).group(1)
'aaa'
>>> re.search( r'\[\[([^\]|]*)(?=.*\]\])', '[[aaabbb]]' ).group(1)
'aaabbb'
```

Comment: Thank you for providing concise answer and explanation.
I should read more articles about regular expression.

Comment: Only one thing to note - this won't handle nested brackets (and in fact a regex wouldn't in general anyway without the help of a counter).